# no me funciona correctamente un bucle c++

Tags: c++, c

llevo intentando programar un calendario en el que el usuario introduce el numero de dias y el dia en el que empieza el calendario y se imprime en pantalla el conjunto de dias como si de un almanaque se tratara. El problema que al compilar si introduzco 31 dias y que empieze el jueves (3) me aparece el siguiente calendario:

```
L   M   M   J   V   S   D
0   0   0   1   2   3   5   
5   6   7   8   9   10  12  
12  13  14  15  16  17  19  
19  20  21  22  23  24  26  
26  27  28  29  0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

alguna sugerencia para arreglar esto?. Siento mucho la pregunta si parece muy obvia, pero estoy empezando en esto del c++.

Os paso la parte del codigo en la que creo que esta el fallo, en donde ndias es numero total de dias (29, 30 o 31) y pds es el primer dia de la semana (0-> lunes, 1-> martes,....6-> domingo.).
TAM=6
TAM2=7

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

const int TAM=6;
const int TAM2=7;

typedef array<int, TAM> filas;
typedef array<filas,TAM2> matriz;

int pedir_ndias();
int pedir_diasemana();
void calendario(matriz& m, int ndias, int pds);
void salida_matriz(matriz& m);
///////////////////MAIN////////////////
int main(){

int ndias, pds;
matriz m;

ndias=pedir_ndias();
pds=pedir_diasemana();

calendario(m, ndias, pds);
salida_matriz(m);



return 0;

}
////////////////////////////////////////////

//subprogramas

int pedir_ndias(){
int ndias;
cout << "introduzca numero de dias del mes"<<endl;
cin >> ndias;
return ndias;
}

int pedir_diasemana(){
int pds;
cout << "Introduzca numeracion según dia de la semana" << endl;
cout << "0. Lunes \n";
cout << "1. Martes \n";
cout << "2. Miercoles \n";
cout << "3. Jueves \n";
cout << "4. Viernes \n";
cout << "5. Sabado \n";
cout << "6. Domingo \n";
cin >> pds;
return pds;
}

void calendario(matriz& m, int ndias, int pds){

    for (int i=0; i<TAM; i++){  //for inicializa a 0 la matriz
        for (int j=0; j<TAM2; j++){
        m[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    
int cont=0; //contador para saber cuantos dias van

//primera semana
    
        for (int j = pds; j<TAM2; j++){
            m[0][j] = ++cont;
        }
    
    
//////////resto de semanas////

    for(int i=1; i<TAM; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<TAM2; j++){
            //contador para saber cuantos dias van
            if(cont<ndias){
                m[i][j]= ++cont;
            }
        }
    }
}

void salida_matriz(matriz& m){
    for (int i=0; i<TAM; i++){  
    cout << endl;
    for (int j=0; j<TAM2; j++){
    cout << m[i][j] << "\t";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edite tu pregunta para agregar las iniciales de los dias en el calendario, entendiendo que el primer día es Lunes. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega el calendario "correcto", para mejor entender el problema.

Answer (score 2):

Hay un problema con el contador `cont`. Está contando mal los días.

¿Qué representa `cont`? El número de días impresos. Por tanto, debe partir en cero, no en uno, de manera que siempre refleje la realidad. Asi como está, `cont` es el número de días que está por cumplirse. No es lo mismo.

Cambiando la definición, ahora tengo que incrementar `cont` antes de asignarlo a la matriz y ser consistente con la definición. Para eso voy a usar `++cont` y deshacerme asi de una instrucción.

Voy a cambiar el cuerpo del llenado por este:

```
if (cont < ndias) {
    m[i][j] = ++cont;
}
```

que me parece expresa mejor la idea: Mientras no hayamos completado los días, poner el valor en la matriz. Si no, no hago nada; la celda ya está en cero.

Con todo, el cuerpo de la función se reduce a:

```
void calendario(matriz& m, int ndias, int pds){
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) { //for inicializa a 0 la matriz
        for (int j = 0; j < TAM2; j++) {
            m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    int cont = 0; //contador para saber cuantos dias van

    //primera semana    
    for (int j = pds; j < TAM2; j++) {
        m[0][j] = ++cont;
        }

    //////////resto de semanas////
    for (int i = 1; i < TAM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < TAM2; j++) {
            if (cont < ndias) {
                m[i][j] = ++cont;
            } 
        }
    }
```

**Comprobación**

```
calendario(m, 31, 3);
for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < TAM2; j++) {
        printf("%3d ", m[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

produce:

```
  0   0   0   1   2   3   4 
  5   6   7   8   9  10  11 
 12  13  14  15  16  17  18 
 19  20  21  22  23  24  25 
 26  27  28  29  30  31   0
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigue sin funcionarme el programa.
Como curiosidad he probado a imprimir por pantalla solo la primera fila y tambien se me imprime la segunda fila el primer lugar es decir m[1][0]. He editado el mensaje principal con el codigo completo por si ves algo. 

Gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a hacerlo todo dentro de un único bucle:

```
 void calendario(matriz& m, int ndias, int pds)
 {
     int cont=0;
     for(int i=0; i<35; i++)
     {
         m[i/7][i%7] = 0; // Vamos inicializando la matriz
         // Llenamos la matriz con los días marcados por la
         // variable cont
         if (i >=psd && cont <= nDias)
         {   
            m[i/7][i%7]=cont;
            ++cont;
         }
         // Imprimimos
         cout << m[i/7][i%7] << "\t";
         if (i%7==0 && i!=0) cout <<endl;
    }
}
```

Como verás en la propia inicialización de la matriz ya se puede hacer todo. Observa el uso de los operadores módulo y división para determinar la columna y la fila dentro de la matriz.